# Ajax not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on ajax functionality to count clicks on a button

My ajax code is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function call_user(user_id){ 
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
   data: 'user_id='+user_id,
    url : '<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/ajax/call.php',

  });
      }
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<a href='tel:<?php echo $row['contact']; ?>' onclick='call_user(<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>);'  title='Call'>Call Now</a>
```

Its a `call now` button and onclicking it i'm calling call_user() javascript function.

The logic for counting clicks and db queries are written in `call.php` file

Its working fine in desktop/laptop version. But counter is not incrementing in mobile devices (iphone/android). I guess ajax is not getting called in mobile devices.

What could be the problem. Please help.

Comment: Do you know that `call_user` is definitely being called on those platforms?  Where is the code that calls this function

Comment: Its a good practice to specify dataType in your ajax call.

Comment: Yes it's called from oncliking an HTML button. Its working on desktop.

Comment: @Alok Not if you're only sending data.  The `dataType` parameter is to help jQuery parse any data returned from the server.

Comment: @nilesh can you post that code also, it may be relevant.  If you put an `alert` in `call_user`, do you see that on the mobile devices?

Comment: I _suspect_, but don't know for sure, that because it's a `tel:` link on a mobile device, they're probably trying to initiate a call and not actually firing the `onclick` handler.  Someone with more knowledge of this area may be able to clarify.  If this is the case, you could perhaps set `location.href=` in the onclick instead of using the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried your original code I could not alert anything inside the click event even on a desktop which indicates there may be an issue with your event binding.

I created a jsfiddle where I have bound click events using jquery and a css class and added a data value for the user_id. This is firing the click events on desktop and mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/871af5o0/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.call__link').on('click', function(){
   var user_id = $(this).data('userid');
   alert(user_id);
   jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: 'user_id='+user_id,
        url : '<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/ajax/call.php',
      });
});});

<a class="call__link" href="tel:" title="Call" data-userid="123">Call Now</a>
```

You will notice the alert is being triggered so the ajax call will be initiated.

I originally thought that it may have been tel: hijacking the event but in the jfiddle you will see on mobile both the tel: event and click event are called.

If you try the above example with your live code and it alerts on mobile then we can confirm that it is the ajax request itself that will be the area to focus on.

Comment: thanks buddy for your efforts.but user_id is not getting alerted

Comment: Have you got any JS errors? And also what mobile device are using?